# python mechanizeでHTTP Error 999

Tags: python

これまでうまく動いていた以下のスクリプトを実行すると、エラーが出るようになりました。

```
import requests
import mechanize

b = mechanize.Browser();
b.set_handle_robots(False);
b.set_handle_refresh(False);
url = "http://info.finance.yahoo.co.jp/history/?code=9783";
h = b.open(url);
```

他のurl(`http://www.google.com`など)ではうまくいきます。
なぜでしょうか？

エラーは以下のとおりです。

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 999: Unable to process request at this time -- error 999
```

Comment: すみません。自己解決しました。実行環境側の問題だったようです。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しているようですが、調べたので書いておきます。

[Rate Limits for Yahoo Finance (999 error codes)? - YDN Forums](http://www.yahooapis.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Rate-Limits-for-Yahoo-Finance-999/1247924431000-b6592497-c06d-32f9-a498-5569805b59ea) によると、同一のIPアドレスから、1時間に400回アクセスすると999エラーを返す例があるようです。

時間あたりのアクセス回数を抑制すれば解決するのではないかと思います。

Comment: yahoo側の問題なんですね。ありがとうございました。

Comment: あなたのコードの問題ですよ。速度制限をかけなさい、ということです。